# ADODB.Recordset addnew with an Oracle package field

Tags: oracle, vb6, ado, recordset

Hy guys.
I have a visual basic 6 program with an Oracle DB. When i add a record to table i do:

```
Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Title") = "Titolo"
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Author") = "Autore"
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("IP") = "10.0.1.1"
Adodc1.Recordset.Update
```

This routine is ok, but i want to set IP with an oracle function: **sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')**

When i have modified my routine in

```
Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Title") = "Titolo"
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Author") = "Autore"
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("IP") = "sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')"
Adodc1.Recordset.Update
```

the field of table is always null.
There are workaround for this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think that should work?  Isn't it just going to insert that function as a string literal?

Comment: No, it inserts IP field the string "sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')"... Can i modify fields type?

Comment: That is what it should do!  I don't think you can call an Oracle function from ADO -- like that anyway. You could form an INSERT statement and use that

Comment: Ok thanks. I've searched and try all Ado fields type, but nothing...I convert my code to execute builded sql statement string. :-(

Comment: I have added an answer to that effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple answer is you cannot do it that way. As it is written you are assigning the fixed string 'sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')' into the 'IP' field.

To use that function you will have to construct an INSERT statement and execute it directly. Somethink like

INSERT INTO your_table ( Title, Author, IP )
SELECT 'Titolo', 'Autore', sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')

Alternatively you could create a stored procedure and execute that (which might be better in the long run)